# ASP.NET localhost routing issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-6, asp.net-mvc-routing

A call to localhost ( using the VS 2008 integrated webserver ) is not working ( empty page.. )

```
http://localhost:6666
```

but a call to a remote IIS

```
http://asdf.com/MyApp
```

is routed to the correct controler and method (SearchController -> Search )... MyApp is the IIS directory in which the folder "Controller" is...

The routingcode:

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default",                                              // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}",                           // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Search", action = "Search", id = "" }  // Parameter defaults
        );
```

How to solve this, so that it's working on both webservers?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, that's a tricky one, it's gotten me before too. Follow this:
http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/26/asp.net-mvc-on-iis-6-walkthrough.aspx

Comment: mhm, i appenend the a "MapRoute" with an empty string ( like "Root" on the linked page ) but unfortunately it doesn't work out..

Comment: You should probably really try it exactly like he has it there first.